# In which order does Wordpress execute plugins?

Tags: wordpress

What intelligence does WordPress use to register & execute plugins?

I currently have a plugin that is dependent on another plugin, as it uses hooks defined there, so does the ordering of these plugins matter?

Comment: From wordpress.stackexchange.com: [In what order does WordPress load plugin files?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/63141/in-what-order-does-wordpress-load-plugin-files)

Comment: As for the hooks, if they are using the action/filter API, it shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress executes it's plugins based on the order specified in the database.

However, wordpress will usually handle the loading of plugins in a safe manner as their are guidelines for wordpress developers to build plugins. Though these guidelines are not always followed, most if not all major / popular wordpress plugins are built according to these standards.

If a specific plugin requires another plugin, the required file(s) will be loaded accordingly in order to accommodate the requesting plugin.

Comment: so in other words wordpress takes care of the ordering/calling of hooks used in other hooks etc?

Comment: Yes, for the most part, Wordpress does a pretty good job at handling this for you. The default order should not be tampered with unless you feel very comfortable about what's going on.